# Is it possible to set/update jCrop aspect ratio on select box change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jcrop

Is it possible to set/update jCrop aspect  ratio on select box change?
I've added a ratio and selection variables and worked fine statically but can't get it to work on select change while the select alerts the right values

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var ratio = 4 / 3
        var selection = '[0,0,4,3]';
        $("#ratio").change(function () {
            var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
            ratio = text;
            val = $(this).val();
            selection = '[0,0,' + val + ']';
            alert(ratio)
        }).trigger('change');

        // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
        var jcrop_api,
            boundx,
            boundy,
        // Grab some information about the preview pane
            $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
            $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
            $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),
            xsize = $pcnt.width(),
            ysize = $pcnt.height();
            console.log('init', [xsize, ysize]);

        $('#target').Jcrop({
            onChange: updatePreview,
            onSelect: updateCoords,
            setSelect: selection,
            aspectRatio: ratio
        }, function () {
            // Use the API to get the real image size
            var bounds = this.getBounds();
            boundx = bounds[0];
            boundy = bounds[1];
            // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
            jcrop_api = this;
            // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
            $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
        });
        $('#coords').on('change', 'input', function (e) {
            var x1 = $('#X').val(),
                y1 = $('#Y').val();
            jcrop_api.setSelect([x, y]);
        });

        function updatePreview(c) {
            if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                var rx = xsize / c.w;
                var ry = ysize / c.h;
                $pimg.css({
                    width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        };
    });

    function updateCoords(c) {
        $('#X').val(Math.round(c.x));
        $('#Y').val(Math.round(c.y));
        $('#W').val(Math.round(c.w));
        $('#H').val(Math.round(c.h));
    };
```

And here is the select values and text which I'm not stick to:

```
<select  id="ratio">
    <option value="4,3">1.3</option>
    <option value="6,3">1.6</option>
    <option value="9,3">.8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the Aspect Ratio by:

```
 jcrop_api.setOptions({
    aspectRatio: yourAspectRatioValue
 });
```

In your code,

```
$("#ratio").change(function () {
        var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
        ratio = text;
        val = $(this).val();
        selection = '[0,0,' + val + ']';
        jcrop_api.setOptions({
        aspectRatio: ratio
        }); 
  }).trigger('change');
```

But place this code after the code where you are applying jCrop on the image.

Comment: I tried everywhere in my code but didn't work with my variables

Comment: oh, worked .. I tried before but was returning an error and didn't pay attention it was the api reference :) .. thank you

Comment: sorry, is it possible to add setSelect too? I used setSelect: selection, aspectRatio: ratio and it goes to the top left corner when add as static or as variables from selectbox

Comment: a last question if you got time, sorry for that. Is it possible to us updateCoords to set inputs values when change select? or what that (c) variable is? how to send from a function out of $('#target').Jcrop() function and returning NaN. Thank yo again

Comment: The problem is how to pass a value from the select and combine with the selection array .... '[0,0,' + val + ']' is not suitable to work